# First Huffman Compression Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, compression

I decided to take up learning c++ recently, so I coded a Huffman compression algorithm. I'm particularly interested in critique of my c++ techniques (pointers, references, best practices, etc), but I am open to any comments you have.

Thanks for you time!

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<char, int> weight_pair;

struct node {
    int weight;
    node *parent = NULL;
    node *children[2] = {NULL, NULL};
    std::string content;
};

bool compareNodeWeights(const node *node1, const node *node2) {

    return (node1 -> weight) < (node2 -> weight);
}

//builds a binary tree from an alphabet and an associated set of weights
node *build_tree(const std::map<char, int> &weights){
    std::deque<node*> nodes;

    for (auto const &x : weights) {
        node *leaf_node = new node;

        leaf_node -> weight = x.second;
        leaf_node -> content = std::string(1, x.first);

        nodes.push_back(leaf_node);
    }

    while (nodes.size() > 1) {

        std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), compareNodeWeights);

        node* new_node = new node;

        new_node -> weight = nodes[0] -> weight + nodes[1] -> weight;
        new_node -> content = nodes[0] -> content + nodes[1] -> content;
        nodes[0] -> parent = new_node;
        nodes[1] -> parent = new_node;
        new_node -> children[0] = nodes[0];
        new_node -> children[1] = nodes[1];

        nodes.erase(nodes.begin());
        nodes.erase(nodes.begin());

        nodes.push_back(new_node);
    }

    return nodes[0];

}

//traverses the tree to find the prefix code for a given leaf node in a tree
std::deque<bool> find_prefix_code(const node *leaf) {
    std::deque<bool> result;
    const node *curr_node = leaf;

    while (curr_node -> parent != NULL) {
        if (curr_node -> parent -> children[0] -> content == curr_node -> content) {
            result.push_front(0);   
        }

        else {
            result.push_front(1);   
        }

        curr_node = curr_node -> parent;

    }

    return result;
}

std::vector<bool> compress(const std::string &message, const node *tree) {
    std::vector<bool> result;

    std::vector<const node*> open;
    open.push_back(tree);

    std::map<char, std::deque<bool>> prefix_codes;

    while (open.size() > 0) {
        const node* curr_node = open[0];


        if (curr_node -> content.size() == 1){

            prefix_codes.insert( std::pair<char, std::deque<bool>>(curr_node -> content[0], find_prefix_code(curr_node)) ); 
        }

        else {
            open.push_back(curr_node -> children[0]);   
            open.push_back(curr_node -> children[1]);   
        }

        open.erase(open.begin());   
    }

    for (const char c : message) {
        for (const bool &b : prefix_codes[c]) {
            result.push_back(b);
        }       
    }


    return result;
}

std::string decompress(const std::vector<bool> &data, const node *tree) {
    const node *curr_node = tree;
    std::string result = "";

    for (const bool b : data) {
        int direction = b;

        curr_node = curr_node -> children[direction];

        if (curr_node ->content.size() == 1) {
            result += curr_node -> content;
            curr_node = tree;   
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void print_compressed(const std::vector<bool> &data) {
    std::cout << "Compressed data: ";

    for (const bool b : data) {
        std::cout << b;

    }

    std::cout <<  std::endl;
}


void delete_tree(node *tree) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        if (tree -> children[i] != NULL) {
            delete_tree(tree -> children[i]);
        }
    }

    delete tree;
}

int main() {
    std::map<char, int> weights;

    weights.insert(weight_pair(' ', 3));
    weights.insert(weight_pair('a', 3));
    weights.insert(weight_pair('d', 3));
    weights.insert(weight_pair('b', 1));
    weights.insert(weight_pair('c', 1));

    node *tree = build_tree(weights);



    std::vector<bool> compressed_message = compress("a cab dab bad", tree);
    print_compressed(compressed_message);   

    std::string message = decompress(compressed_message, tree);
    std::cout << "Decompressed data: " << message << std::endl;

    delete_tree(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Do you target a specific C++ version? Your code seems to use C++03 only and none of the more recent C++ features except for the range-based `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typedef for `weight_pair` but only use it in main to fill the map.

`node::children` should be unique_ptr. That way you don't need delete_tree. However you will need at most 2*n nodes to be allocated so you can preallocate those in a `std::vector<node>` and avoid calling make_unique on each new node.

In `build_tree` you pull that map apart to build a `node*` array so you may as well have just passed a `std::vector<weight_pair>`.

You can avoid using the `std::deck` by reverse sorting a `std::vector` (so the lowest elements end up at the back ready to get popped of).

```
while (nodes.size() > 1) {
    std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), reverseCompareNodeWeights);

    unique_ptr<node> new_node = std::make_unique<node>(); 
    //or node* new_node = allocated_nodes[next++]; // if preallocated.
    unique_ptr<node>& back1 = nodes[nodes.size()-1];
    unique_ptr<node>& back2 = nodes[nodes.size()-2];
    new_node -> weight = back1 -> weight + back2 -> weight;
    new_node -> content = back2 -> content + back2 -> content;
    back1->parent = new_node;
    back2->parent = new_node;
    new_node -> children[0] = std::move(back1);
    new_node -> children[1] = std::move(back2);

    nodes.pop_back();
    nodes.back(std::move(new_node));

}
```

Or you could use the std::heap operations

```
std::make_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), compareNodeWeights);

while (nodes.size() > 1) {
    std::pop_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), compareNodeWeights);
    std::pop_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end()-1, compareNodeWeights);

    //identical to above

    nodes.pop_back();
    nodes.back() = std::move(new_node);
    std::push_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), compareNodeWeights);
}
```

---

Compressing or decompressing bit by bit using this tree is going to be very slow. It will result in  a cache miss per bit of output.

instead you can make a lookup table. For compression this is straightforward it will be a `std::array<compress_value>` where `compress_value` is

```
struct compress_value {
    uint code;
    uint code_size;
}
```

and the compression main loop will be:

```
std::vector<uint8> output;

uint64 outputbuff; //filled from least significant bit first
uint filled;
for(char c : input){
    compress_value value = compress_table[c];
    outputbuff |= value.code << filled;
    filled += value.code_size;
    while(filled > 8){
        output.pushback(outputbuff & 0xff);
        outputbuff  = outputbuff >> 8;
        filled -= 8;
    }
}
```

---

Decompressing will be similar. But instead you will have a lookup table that is as large as \$ 2^{\text{max code size}}\$

Each entry in the decompression table will contain at index i the character where `i & mask` is the code for the value.

That is

```
for(table_value value : table){
    for(uint c = value.code; c < table_size; c += 1<<value.code_size){
        decompress_table[c].ch = value.ch;
        decompress_table[c].code_size = value.code_size;
    }
}
```

The decompression main loop will be:

```
uint64 input_buff = read_up_to_8_bytes(input, end); //reads least significant byte first
uint filled = 64;
while(input < end){
    decompress_value value = decompress_table[input_buff & decompress_mask];
    output.push_back(value.ch);
    input_buff = input_buff >> value.code_size;
    filled -= value.code_size;
    if(filled < max_code_size){
         while(filled < 56 && (input != end)){
             input++;
             filled += 8;
         }
         input_buff = read_up_to_8_bytes(input, end);
         if(filled != 0)
             input_buff = input_buff >> (64-filled);
    }
}
```

instead of all those explicit bounds checks you can add a new symbol that signifies the end of the bit stream and overallocate the input buffer by at least 8 bytes. Though that requires that the stream was not corrupted. The compromise is to only have the bounds check on the outer loop.